# Insert non-Refinery link into Refinery navigation menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

Refinery generates its navigation menu in the `_menu` and `_menu_branch` helpers. I want to keep the provided logic since it allows a user to create a new page. However, let's say I have a model `Product` and I want to insert a link to the `show` action of `Product` in the navigation menu. What's the proper Refinery way to do that?

Comment: Nobody has any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do it is create the page in the pages dashboard, and in advanced setting you just fill the redirect to `/products/awesome` or whatever the product slug or id is.

You can see how I did it on: http://tigrepictures.com/